# Spring auto-configuration properties validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating my own auto-configuration for spring boot to configure a rest client that connecting to my company's REST ESB, there should be some basic properties like the URL and credentials in (application.properties or .yml).

I was wondering:

1. Should I be doing validation? is it correct to do it?
2. If I should, where to validate (assert) that the configuration (e.g. URL) is provided or not? should it be in the auto-configuration class (inside the method that uses `@Bean`)?

My code is:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(EsbClientService.class)
   @ConditionalOnClass({EsbClientService.class,EsbSpringClientServiceImpl.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(EsbRestClientProperties.class)
public class EsbClientAutoConfiguration {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(EsbClientAutoConfiguration.class);
@Autowired
private EsbRestClientProperties properties;

@Bean
public EsbClientService esbClientService(){
    //TODO  check all properties are set!
    logger.info("Auto Configure EsbClientService using EsbSpringClientServiceImpl");
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    EsbResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new EsbResponseErrorHandler();
    clientFactory.setReadTimeout(properties.getReadTimeout());
    clientFactory.setConnectTimeout(properties.getConnectTimeout());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientFactory);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    EsbClientService service = new EsbSpringClientServiceImpl(restTemplate, properties);

    logger.info("Auto Configure EsbClientService using EsbSpringClientServiceImpl Done");
    return service;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `EsbRestClientProperties`... You can add JSR-303 annotations to it and it will be validated when binding the properties.

Comment: I don't want to add more dependencies, and it's just only few properties. what I'm asking is : 1- should I do validation? 2- if I should, then where

Comment: It should already be there as it is a core dependency for Spring Boot... If properties are required then yes you want to validate.